# Restricting access to the Keycloak Admin Console

Tags: keycloak

Is there any way to configure Keycloak 2.2.1 so that the admin console is not accessible from a remote IP?

Basically, I'd like to set it up like the Wildfly admin console where you can access it locally on the server but cannot access it remotely.

Answer (score 7):

According to Keycloak docs, each realm has a dedicated Admin Console that can be accessed by going to the URL **/auth/admin/{realm-name}/console**.

I think you could block this URL for external access, keeping attention for others URIs that may be used for Keycloak REST API and for the external modules that external apps could download also (like javascript module). The same approach could also be applied for JBoss EAP console admin at default port 9990.

JBoss EAP have additional features that could be used for blocking specific IP range or restrict access only to the local server.

You can also apply a specific undertow filter to block external access. 
See example below:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                    <filter-ref name="proxy-peer" />
                    <filter-ref name="restrict-admin-console-access" />
                    <access-log pattern="%h %l %u [%t] &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot;" />
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                    <filter name="request-dumper" class-name="io.undertow.server.handlers.RequestDumpingHandler" module="io.undertow.core" />
                    <request-limit name="limit-connections" queue-size="100" max-concurrent-requests="1200" />
                    <filter name="proxy-peer" module="io.undertow.core" class-name="io.undertow.server.handlers.ProxyPeerAddressHandler" />
                    <expression-filter module="io.undertow.core" name="restrict-admin-console-access" expression="path-prefix(/auth/admin/master/console/) -&gt; ip-access-control(default-allow=false, acl={'127.0.0.1 allow'})" />
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
```

Reference:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18412